# How to enable dispatchEvent to run through Content-Security-Policy without 'unsafe-inline'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using intel xdk which has some built in code. I've added a meta tag for CSP and I'm trying to fix the code so that I don't need 'unsafe-inline'

There is this code that is built in that CSP won't allow when unsafe-inline isn't added that I'm not sure on how to change, it looks like this:

```
    $.fn.trigger = function(event, data, props) {
        if (typeof event === "string"){
            props=props || {};
            event = parse(event);
            props.ns=event.ns;
            event = $.Event(event.e, props);
        }
        event.data = data;
        for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
            this[i].dispatchEvent(event); //THIS is the row that fails the CSP control
        }
        return this;
    };
```

I've managed to fix some normal inline onclick events by switching to click addEventListeners. However I'm unaware on how the dispatchEvent can be changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: That's a jquery code for the definition of `$(selector).trigger(event)`?

Comment: Due security reasons, you can't dispatch an onclick event if the user don't make any action.

Comment: Does it look like i can get around this without adding 'unsafe-inline' ?

Comment: I don't know what `unsafe-inline` is. Sorry. jQuery code crashes because things you do, not because jQuery code is wrong. Add your code, not the jquery code and we'll can see